# Why does the sonaqube gradle plugin creates jacoco-overall.exec files?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

in our multi module gradle build we use jacoco to measure code coverage, and we are creating a aggregated jacoco-exec file. To make the sonarqube plugin use this file for creating the reports, we configured it as followed:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "$project.rootDir/build/jacoco/jacoco.exec"
    }
}
```

When running the sonarqube plugin with gradle sonarqube, it prints the following messages:

```
10:56:00.064 INFO  - Analysing C:\A\Projekte\sqs\git\build\sonar\de.kvb.sqs_admin-db\jacoco-overall.exec
10:56:00.116 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
10:56:00.116 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 116 ms
...
10:56:00.718 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
10:56:00.720 INFO  - Analysing C:\A\Projekte\sqs\git\build\jacoco\jacoco.exec
10:56:00.738 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
...
10:56:06.442 INFO  - Analysing C:\A\Projekte\sqs\git\build\sonar\de.kvb.sqs_admin-gui\jacoco-overall.exec
10:56:06.453 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
10:56:06.453 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 31 ms
...
10:56:06.833 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
10:56:06.837 INFO  - Analysing C:\A\Projekte\sqs\git\build\jacoco\jacoco.exec
10:56:06.863 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
```

Two questions:

1) Why does the sonarqube plugin create all those jacoco-overall.exec files?

2) Why does the sonarqube plugin not only use my jacoco.exec file for generating the coverage reports, but also all those jacoco-overall.exec files?

thx,
  Martin.